# Firefox Add-on SDK Attach Content Script Once

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  icon: "./icon16.png", 
  label: "Test Button",
  onClick: function() {   
    tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: ['./content.js']
    }); 
  }
});
```

I am attaching a `content script` file to the active tab by a toolbar button click.

How can I know if the content script is already attached to the `activeTab` or not? I do not want to add multiple content scripts to the tab. If there is any attached content script, I need to remove it.

`Toggle` button does not help me. Button does work tab specific way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.attach` returns a worker. Put it in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with the tab object as key. If there already is an entry present for that tab, don't attach.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if I attach the content script twice? Does it override the first one or simply attached another script with its own scope?

Comment: you can easily determine that yourself